# ionic capacitor filesystem api write a personal folder in internal storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filesystems, capacitor

I need an information.

On my phone several apps creates a folder with the package name on internal storage.
Those folders are browsable from pc.

I would like to create a folder in internal storage for my app to store some generated images and pdf.

Actually the file are stored in file:///data/user/0/[packageName]/files/temp.pdf but this folder is not accessible from pc.

If I use Documents folder I get this error
Error: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/temp.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
why?
I've granted read and write on external storage

So... is it possible to create a personal folder on internal storage?
I cannot find anything on the web...

this is my simple code

```
  const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: fileName,
      data: base64Data,

      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Capacitor FileSystem, you can choose where to write your file with the `directory` enum.

If you take a look at the docs here https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#directory

You can see there are `Directory.Data` to hold applications file that will remove if you uninstall the app.

> The Data directory On iOS it will use the Documents directory. On
> Android it’s the directory holding application files. Files will be
> deleted when the application is uninstalled.

You can also use `Directory.Cache` to allow the system to erase them if user clears the cache in the settings. The following is working for me:

```js
    const writeSecretFile = async () => {
    await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: 'text.txt',
        data: "This is a test",
        directory: Directory.Cache,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
    });
    };

    const readSecretFile = async () => {
    const contents = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path: 'text.txt',
        directory: Directory.Cache,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
    });

    console.log('secrets:', JSON.stringify(contents));
    };

    writeSecretFile();
    readSecretFile();
```

I hope it helps.